# What assembly files does Windows Phone designer of Visual Studio use?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, designer

I am building a Windows utility that shows the user interface of a Windows Phone page. Visual Studio has similar designer that shows how the XAML of the selected page looks like. Visual Studio's designer must use some special assemblies that actually render XAML of the page just like on a real device.

[image: Windows Phone designer of Visual Studio]

I would like to use the same assemblies as the designer of Visual Studio uses. What are those assemblies?

Comment: Attach the debugger to xdesproc.exe and take a look at which modules are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

These are all internal stuff for VS and Blend. The following blogpost gives you some insight into how this works under the covers: http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/xamluipresenter-what-are-you/
Albeit not WP specific the same applies to phone. However this is NOT supported for use anywhere else.

I'm wondering what your use case is? There might be something better and supported for you to use.

Comment: I am making a localization tool that localizes RESX and XAML resources of Windows Phone assemblies. I need XAML rendering to provide a visual preview of the localized XAML.